# list output truncated - How to expand listed variables with str() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, output, truncated

I have a data.frame `df` with 600+ variables.  I'm writing a function that automates the creation of columns and need to visually check them once.

The `str` function provides a good summary:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   29 obs. of  602 variables:
 $ uniqueSessionsIni: POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 16:00:00" "2015-01-05 17:00:00" ...
 $ uniqueSessionsEnd: POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:59:00" "2015-01-05 16:59:00" "2015-01-05 17:59:00" ...
 $ m0p0             : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:00" ...
 $ m1p0             : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:01:00" "2015-01-05 15:01:00" "2015-01-05 15:01:00" ...
 $ m2p0             : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:02:00" "2015-01-05 15:02:00" "2015-01-05 15:02:00" ...
```

and it goes on...
but truncates the output, as below:

```
$ m33p1            : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:34:00" "2015-01-05 15:34:00" "2015-01-05 15:34:00" ...
$ m34p1            : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:35:00" "2015-01-05 15:35:00" "2015-01-05 15:35:00" ...
$ m35p1            : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:36:00" "2015-01-05 15:36:00" "2015-01-05 15:36:00" ...
$ m36p1            : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:37:00" "2015-01-05 15:37:00" "2015-01-05 15:37:00" ...
[list output truncated]
```

How can I display the full list of 602 variables?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use the argument `list.len`:

```
str(df, list.len=ncol(df))
```

and if you want to print more observations you could set the argument `vec.len`, also have a look at `?str` for documentation of all arguments.

Comment: I cannot get this work in custom time fields. All other fields are affected, but not the custom time fields. Please, see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/q/44026585/54964

Comment: Or `str(df, list.len=Inf)`

Answer (score 13):

By using argument list.len one can choose the number of variables in the data frame to list. There are two options:

a) You choose the number of variables that you want to list;

```
str(df, list.len = 602) # in this case I'm listing 602 variables.
```

b) You choose to list the total number of variables of the data frame (as mentioned by user1981275);

```
str(df, list.len = ncol(df))
```

Check R help for more info

```
> ?str
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, if you want to change the default of `str()` parameter  `list.len` which is set to 99, use

`options(str = strOptions(list.len = 9999))`

then `str(df)` will show all of the variables at once without truncation.