# Send str() output to View()

Tags: r, dataframe, view, metadata

I am investigating the variables in a dataset with 313 variables. 
I am currently printing the [full list of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895044/list-output-truncated-how-to-expand-listed-variables-with-str-in-r) to the output screen using:

```
str(df, list.len=ncol(df))
```

`str()` output is very useful but difficult to read at the output when there window with so many variables.

Is there command, similar to `str()`, but that allows sending the output to the viewer window (`View()`)?

This would be very useful:

```
library(dplyr)    
d %>% str() %>% View()
```

Outputing a dataset with: varnames, vartype, values_string

Does this exist?

Comment: `%>%` is not a base R function. Please list the names of any packages you are using in the body of your question.

Comment: Looking at the manual, `?str`, the answer is no, or at least not directly. From the "value" section: "str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal." Thus, nothing can directly be captured from `str`. Perhaps you can redirect the print statement to a temp file and read it in with `read.table`... From `?View`, this function requires something that can be coerced into a data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like the implementation here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/str-implementation-for-data-frames/ would work. It outputs the results of str() to a data.frame which you can then work with in View().

```
#' Creates a \code{data.frame} version of the str function for data.frames.
#' 
#' Note that this function only works with \code{data.frames}. The function
#' will throw an error for any other object types.
#' 
#' @param n the first n element to show
#' @param width maximum width in characters for the examples to show
#' @param n.levels the first n levels of a factor to show.
#' @param width.levels maximum width in characters for the number of levels to show.
#' @param factor.values function defining how factor examples should be printed.
#'        Possible values are \code{as.character} or \code{as.integer}.
#' @export
#' @examples
#' data(iris)
#' str(iris)
#' strtable(iris)
#' strtable(iris, factor.values=as.integer)
strtable <- function(df, n=4, width=60, 
                     n.levels=n, width.levels=width, 
                     factor.values=as.character) {
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
    tab <- data.frame(variable=names(df),
                      class=rep(as.character(NA), ncol(df)),
                      levels=rep(as.character(NA), ncol(df)),
                      examples=rep(as.character(NA), ncol(df)),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    collapse.values <- function(col, n, width) {
        result <- NA
        for(j in 1:min(n, length(col))) {
            el <- ifelse(is.numeric(col),
                         paste0(col[1:j], collapse=', '),
                         paste0('"', col[1:j], '"', collapse=', '))
            if(nchar(el) <= width) {
                result <- el
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if(length(col) > n) {
            return(paste0(result, ', ...'))
        } else {
            return(result)
        }
    }

    for(i in seq_along(df)) {
        if(is.factor(df[,i])) {
            tab[i,]$class <- paste0('Factor w/ ', nlevels(df[,i]), ' levels')
            tab[i,]$levels <- collapse.values(levels(df[,i]), n=n.levels, width=width.levels)
            tab[i,]$examples <- collapse.values(factor.values(df[,i]), n=n, width=width)
        } else {
            tab[i,]$class <- class(df[,i])[1]
            tab[i,]$examples <- collapse.values(df[,i], n=n, width=width)
        }

    }

    class(tab) <- c('strtable', 'data.frame')
    return(tab)
}

#' Prints the results of \code{\link{strtable}}.
#' @param x result of code \code{\link{strtable}}.
#' @param ... other parameters passed to \code{\link{print.data.frame}}.
#' @export
print.strtable <- function(x, ...) {
    NextMethod(x, row.names=FALSE, ...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `capture.output` to get what you want. However, it does not play well with `magrittr`s pipe. The following works:

```
library("magrittr") # The package and some toy data
obj <- list(a = list(b = list()), c = list(), d = numeric(10))

capture.output(obj %>% str) %>% View
```

or alternatively:

```
obj %>% capture.output(str(.)) %>% View
```

The following 'naive' chaining does *not* work:

```
obj %>% str %>% capture.output %>% View
```

Comment: I know this is about 2 years old but this works for storing it in CSV (inspired by your soluton): 
capture.output(obj %>% str) %>% write.csv("filename.csv")

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that should work:

```
str_tbl <- function(x, n=5) {
  data.frame(Variable = names(x),
             Classe = sapply(x, typeof),
             Values = sapply(x, function(x) paste0(head(x, n = n), 
               collapse = ", ")),
             row.names = NULL)
}
```

Then just do `View(str_tbl(df))` where `df` is your dataframe of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like

```
View(capture.output(str(x <- 1:5)))
```